# HSI KG 525 PNI non slaved or only slaved?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, avionics, easa-regulations, piper-pa-28

I'm in Germany and currently on a project about the avionics of an older airplane (PA28). Here is a link to a former [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aviation/comments/6sfj2i/need_help_identifying_the_instruments/) question.

My Prof. and me want to update the Avionics now - he asked me to do a bit of research - it is quite a good exercise for me and i learn lot this practical way (i'll become an aircraft engineer)!. I do the prework for our maintenance company and they'll supervise my work/planning.

The main idea is to install new:

- Garmin GNS430
- Garmin GMA340
- Insight G4 + Sensorics
- Becker AR6203 22
- KI - 525A or Garmin G5 DG/HSI
- Insight G4 for experimental stuff (UAS courses with our piper)

This avionic stays, but will be reconnected

- KN53 (with GS) – goes to KI 204
- KI 204
- KAP 100 (AP)

Will be removed:

- GPS150
- KI 203 - Insight G4 will come here instead
- KN53 (w/o GS)
- KY 196 (2x COM)

Right now i have the DG - KG107 in it, but my professor wants to update it to a HSI.. [image: Here is a image of our Dashboard]

- Now the question is if a KI-525A has a built-in gyro or is there only the possibility to connect it with the KG102 (which we dont have)?
- I would like to have the new Garmin G5 DG/HSI but it seems that it [doesn't have an EASA STC](https://www.easa.europa.eu/download/stc/STC_WebList.pdf). Garmin is kinda quiet.  What do you think - should we install the G5 (DG/HSI) and hope for a STC or pick another HSI (maybe Century)

EDIT: Took 3 questions off the topic

Comment: [3]: http://%20%20https://www.easa.europa.eu/download/stc/STC_WebList.pdf

Comment: Don't install non-STC'd equipment in your aircraft, it may be a very expensive mistake, who knows when/if Garmin will STC your aircraft. What country is this for, I'm guessing US?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! You should consider splitting your question since you are asking multiple things at once. Also you have the ability to edit your question if you need to change anything. You can read the [How to ask](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for some more details on how to post a good question on this site.

Comment: @Ron Beyer Its in Germany (EASA). Why would you guess US? Is my english so non-british :-D? Yeah i would neither like to do it..

Comment: @JimyPP I could not post more then 2 links.

Comment: A well written and documented question. I hope that you may receive a useful answer here.

Answer (score -1):

[The G5/430 combination was approved by EASA back in February!](https://www.garmin.com/en-US/blog/aviation/easa-approves-g5-certificated-aircraft-europe/) No reason why you can't use it. Some advice for you, learning how to use Google search is an invaluable skill for any aircraft engineer. :)

Comment: The G5/430 is not the issue. It's the DG/HSI Combination which is not approved by EASA. Like i read earlier and like i read now this article says that it is approved only as an attitude indicator aka Flight Instrument. 

I honestly know how to google but sometimes i would like to hear new opinions on a topic. 

I'll paste the official answer from Garmin sooner or later this day

Comment: I didn't read it that way. It says that it can be installed in the place of the primary attitude indicator but does a lot more than that.

Comment: To clarify, I read the press release as telling you -where- to install it, but not what it is authorized to do. Looks like the G5 can also be a flight director, which is pretty cool, and makes sense given the features of the 430 and 430W. BTW, don't forget the 430 can be upgraded to WAAS. That adds a huge benefit when flying any kind of approach. Long time ago, [I reviewed the Garmin IQ3600 based on the PalmPilot for Aero-News w/a WAAS receiver.](http://www.aero-news.net/index.cfm?do=main.textpost&id=eba34ae0-ec04-4785-91b5-f28841c18b7f) On the ground, it could point to exact house numbers!

Comment: @JuanJimenez That bit about learning to use google is patronising. Why are we all here?

Comment: @Koyovis Among other things, to learn what resources are available to engineers to do their jobs. If you don't know why you are here, I can't help you with that.